# gridSearchCV performance measurement

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, grid-search

I have an assignment and it asks me to:

> Improve the performance of the models from the previous step with
> hyperparameter tuning and select a final optimal model using grid
> search based on a metric (or metrics) that you choose. Choosing an
> optimal model for a given task (comparing multiple regressors on a
> specific domain) requires selecting performance measures, for example,
> R2 (coefficient of determination) and/or RMSE (root mean squared error)
> to compare the model performance.

I used this code for hyperparameter tuning:

```py
model_example = GradientBoostingRegressor()
parameters = {'learning_rate': [0.1, 1], 
              'max_depth': [5,10]}

model_best = GridSearchCV(model_example,
                          param_grid=parameters,
                          cv=2, scoring='r2').fit(X_train_new,y_train_new)
model_best.best_estimator_
```

I found the `learning_rate=0.1` and `max_depth=5`. I have chosen `scoring='r3'` as a performance measure but it doesn't have any effect on my model accuracy when I used this code for providing my best model:

```py
my_best_model = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,
                                          max_depth=5).fit(X_train_new,y_train_new)
my_best_model.score(X_train_new,y_train_new)
```

Do you know what is wrong with my work?

Comment: You should use `model_best.best_estimator_` as your model, since fitting a new one with the same hyperparameters probably won't give you the same score as the one found with gridsearch due to the fact that you haven't set a random state.

Comment: what I do now is the to use gridSearchCV to find learning_rate and max_depth. Then I use these two with GradientBoostingRegressor. I have a random state for finding X_train and X_test. I expected to get different learning_rate and max_depth when I change 'scoring'. but it doesn't make any change!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Are you asking why you find the same combination of hyperparameters optimizing for different metrics?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: Oh, well R^2 and rmse are kind of related, since they both measure squared distance from the real value and your prediction. Although in your case is probably due to the size of your search space, you might want to add a couple more options to your hyperparameters. Another way could be to swap one for mean absolute error.

Comment: based on this (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) there is no R2 as scoring method. I only found R2 scoring for GradientBoostingRegressor which doesnt have any effect

Comment: they're called 'r2' and 'neg_mean_absolute_error'